# Making any tweet favourite through iOS 5 twitter API

Tags: ios5, twitter

I am working on making a twitter client app. One of the requirement of client is also to mark the specifice tweets as favourite from the app. I am searching on this for two days but no clue.. Can any one plz guide me if it is possible to do so through ios 5's twitter API on not. If yes then how??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes thats possible using Twitter and Accounts framework:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
        // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
           ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];


           NSString* urlString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/create/%d.json", tweetID];
           TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] 
                                             parameters:nil 
                                          requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];


           [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

           [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
               NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i",  [urlResponse statusCode]];
               NSLog(@"%@", output);

             }];

            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Also take a look at the Twitter REST API documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/favorites/create/%3Aid